# NullReferenceException when initializing MySqlDB.MySql.MySql() buried in DLL

Tags: mysql, nullreferenceexception

This is not a standard nullreferenceexception question because there are no objects instantiated that this initialization relies on, only namespaces

I've been racking my brain for a couple of days on this one. The code works on another developer's machine (who is no longer here), so I have installed MySQL and imported the configuration, but I keep coming back to this exception. `MySqlDB.MySQL` is a namespace and `MySQL()` is just a method stub from the metadata.

The DLL is MySqlDB.dll, which lives with the project.

I have confirmed the executable by itself doesn't work on my machine either, so I know it is an environmental issue. Here's the list of other things I've tried (the application also has a dependency on SQL Server).

- install SQL Server Express
- uninstall SQL Server Express
- install SQL Server
- install Excel 2016 version for mysql plugin for Excel that was missing
- moved executable from developer's machine to attempt running outside of Visual Studio - confirmed environmental issue
- checked .NET version
- Remove and Add MySQL DLL
- Reinstall MySQL
- Copied MySQL DLLs from GAC on developer's machine
- Export and Import MySQL DB Configuration

`var mySql = new MySqlDB.MySql.MySql();`

> at MySqlDB.MySql.MySql.c909228df886bcca197ed06f91ce6af71()
>      at MySqlDB.MySql.MySql..ctor()
>      at BCS_UI.App.Register() in c:\GitCode\Windows_UI_Beta\UI\UI\App.xaml.cs:line 47
>      at BCS_UI.App.Application_Startup(Object sender, StartupEventArgs e) in c:\GitCode\Windows_UI_Beta\UI\UI\App.xaml.cs:line 23
>      at System.Windows.Application.OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
>      at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1_0(Object unused)
>      at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
>      at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)

Comment: "I know it is an environmental issue" Did you check both machines are running on 32 or 64 bits and installed the correct bits related software?

Comment: Are you asking if both machines are running the same version of the software or do you mean 32/64 bit Windows version?

Comment: Software versions and windows versions..

Comment: Good question.  Machines are all x64 and target CPU was set to "any" until I changed it to x86 the other day in attempt to fix this issue.  Don't ask me why.  Will try to reproduce by setting them to x64.